# Does Brazil issue a document certifying that one has never been married?

Tags: legal-terms, brazil

Is there a certificate issued by the Government of Brazil to prove that an individual has never been married before? If so, how is it called?

Some countries call it *Certificate of No Marriage* and others *Single Status Certificate*.

Comment: Which individuals? Brazilian citizens?

Answer (score 3):

The only one I can find so far relates to a Brazilian citizen getting married abroad, called a:

- *Consular Declaration of Civil Status*

These are issued by the Consular Authority to:

> Brazilian citizens who intend to marry before a foreign authority within their jurisdiction.
>
> The document is issued in English.

> [Source: gov.br](https://www.gov.br/mre/pt-br/embaixada-helsinque/servicos-consulares/declaracao-consular-de-estado-civil)

(I have yet to find if a comparable certificate is available in-country, for marriage or otherwise, but none of the official guidance sites I have trawled though mention it)